# C programming register values?

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers

In the program below, the second printf statement prints the same mem location and value as the first printf statement.Why?

Is it because the values of the registers were not changed when the second printf statement was called?  The y variable was never initialized, so when printf is called it only finds 'x' on the stack?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo1( int xval ) {

    int x;
    x = xval;

    /* print the address and value of x here */
    printf("x\t | %#x\t\t| %d\n", &x, x);
}

void foo2( int dummy ) {

    int y;

    /* print the address and value of y here */
    printf("y\t | %#x\t\t| %d\n", &y, y);
}


int main() {

    printf("Variable | Memory Location\t| Value\n");
    foo1(7);
    foo2(11);

    return( 0 );
}
```

Output:

```
Variable | Memory Location  | Value
x    | 0xe6ffa3cc       | 7
y    | 0xe6ffa3cc       | 7
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it print the same address ? And you can't expect anything from undefined behaviour, but in your case you're probably right.

Comment: reading an uninitialized value is undefined behavior, so you can't expect any particular output. (by the way, C doesn't specify that two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes must reside at different addresses. C is a high-level abstraction above the hardware. If you want to manually specify and examine memory locations, use assembly, and not C.)

Comment: Because, I think, in all likelihood, foo2 is using the same stack frame as foo1, and they both use the same amounts of the same data, leading to the same addresses.

Comment: @Linuxios is probably close to correct, except that it wouldn't be the same stack frame, but the same space on the stack for each one's stack frame and/or local variables. Croissant has it right, though: the contents of y are undefined, as is its address; thus this behavior may change with a simple change of the program, the compiler, the platform, or even a random bit set somewhere. (Well, OK, the last one's pushing it, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @JoeSewell: Sorry, right. Not the same stack frame, just occupying the same memory area in the stack because their stack frames are (at least for any sane compiler I can think of), the same size.

Comment: @JoeSewell of course this only holds as long as he survives the demons from his nose.

Comment: Haha.  Thank you.  Thats what i was thinking, I was just having difficulty explaining.

Comment: So because y was not initialized, when you reference it, you can't, and therefore printf just prints the values "garbage" that was previously in the register? as explained by ezaquari?

Comment: ** because you can't actually put something on the stack that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `foo1()` you're assigning value `x`, which is located on stack under address `0xe6ffa3cc`. It means that this particular memory region is initialized with value 7.

Inside `foo2` you're printing uninitialized value `y`. This value is also located on stack and I bet it is accidentally under the same address as `x` was before (you're calling function with the same signature, which will probably result in identical stack "layout"). Since `y` is not initialized, it contains "garbage" from previous call, which is 7.

This behaviour is not defined. On different platform (OS, hardware) it may give you different results.